# Reload table not working when app comes to foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, notifications

i want to reload table when app comes to foreground from background, in my app delegate.m i did like this, but its not working

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EnteredForeground"
                                                        object:nil];

}
```

and in my viewController i am working like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(whenAppEnteredIntoForeground:) name:@"EnteredForeground" object:nil];
}
- (void)whenAppEnteredIntoForeground:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"log msg");
    [tblSearch reloadData];
}
```

what should i do? what mistake i am doing? any help please

Comment: you have tried, the reload table method when viewWillAppear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to rebroadcast a notification when the app comes to the foreground, you can register for the notification from your view controller.

In your case, it's likely to be that the view is not loaded until after your secondary notification is sent, which is why your view controller cannot respond to it. Using breakpoints will confirm if this is the case.

Use this instead:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(whenAppEnteredIntoForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

And you don't need to rebroadcast a notification from your appdelegate.

Comment: should i do in view will appear??

Comment: when app comes in forgrond viewWillAppear calls first?

Comment: viewWillAppear is called whenever the view is about to appear. Again. Stick a breakpoint on these methods and follow it through if you are unsure of the order of the calls.

Comment: first i wll try then i will accpt your ans

Comment: What isn't working. The breakpoints? the data reloading, The notifications? Are you still using the notifications for the app coming to the foreground?

Comment: u said not to use notification, just reload table in viewWillAppear. and i set break point which is not working

Comment: i mean when i go from background to forground viewWillAppear don t work

Comment: I've edited the answer, and I've tested this to make sure it works.

Comment: yes it working but my tableView is not refreshing although am working in viewWillAppear

Comment: Is your reload method not being called, or is your tableview not refreshing. Put a breakpoint on one of the datasource methods to see if it is being called. This is basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appEnteredIntoForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)appEnteredIntoForeground:(id)object {

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that your Reload Data must call from main Thread Otherwise it will not be reloaded.

Comment: There is nothing in the code that says it's being loaded off the UI thread.